# Android WebView MediaPlayer can't play a video twice

Tags: android, html, video, webview, android-mediaplayer

I have an activity with a single full screen WebView, which displays a digital signage webapp. The webapp generates html5 video elements with autoplay flags (using react) which should play as soon as they are loaded.

The first time after loading / reloading the WebView, the video is played correctly, but MediaPlayer throws some warnings:

```
cr_MediaResource: [MediaResourceGetter.java:285] ethernet/wifi connection detected
cr_MediaResource: [MediaResourceGetter.java:166] resource has video cr_MediaResource: [MediaResourceGetter.java:195] extracted valid metadata: MediaMetadata[durationInMilliseconds=881360, width=1080, height=1920, success=true]
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.11.4:4100/static/zapped/western_01_rot.mp4 MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer MediaPlayer: getMetadata
MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)
MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
```

If the video is removed and the same or any other video is added, the Video will either not play at all or play for some seconds and then dissapear until the WebView is reloaded. MediaPlayer throws the following errors:

```
cr_MediaResource: [MediaResourceGetter.java:285] ethernet/wifi connection detected
cr_MediaResource: [MediaResourceGetter.java:166] resource has video
cr_MediaResource: [MediaResourceGetter.java:195] extracted valid metadata: MediaMetadata[durationInMilliseconds=881383, width=1080, height=1920, success=true]
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.11.4:4100/static/zapped/western_01_rot.mp4
MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
MediaPlayer: error (-2, 0)
MediaPlayer: getMetadata
MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
MediaPlayer: Error (-2,0)
```

I made sure to set `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` and `webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)`
but the issue persists.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? i m into the same issue right now with only android 4.4.4